# MqttClient sends the one before last message

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, aws-lambda, mqtt, serverless-framework

In my code which is a handler (serverless framework) I push a message to RabbitMQ but the problem is that when I send the first message, the subscribers don't receive anything and with the second one they receive just the first message and the same happens for the rest (when I send a message the previous one is delivered!). Any Idea?

**Edit**: I have replaced the actual code with a very basic and simple code but still the same result.

**Lambda- create.ts**

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, Context, Callback, Handler } from "aws-lambda";
import { config } from "../common/config";
import publish from "../common/publisher";

export const create: Handler = (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context, cb: Callback) => {
    console.log('test started');
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const topic = 'float/push';
    const num = Math.random();
    const message = JSON.stringify({ floatId: num });
    publish(config.PUSH_BROKER_UFRL, config.PUSH_USERNAME, config.PUSH_PASSWORD, topic, message, () => {
        console.log('calling the callback');
        cb(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id: num })
        });
    });
};
```

**publisher.ts**

```
import { Callback } from 'aws-lambda';
import { Client, connect, MqttClient, Packet } from 'mqtt';

function publish(brokerUrl: string, username: string, password: string, topic: string,
                 message: string, callback: (() => void)): void {
    console.log('publish started');
    const client: Client = connect(brokerUrl, {
        username,
        password
    });
    client.options.clientId = 'Cashmanager.portal';
    client.addListener('connect', () => {
        console.log('connected to the queue');
        console.log(`message to publish: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
        client.publish(topic, message, (err, packet) => {
            console.log(`err: ` + err);
            console.log(`packet: ${JSON.stringify(packet)}`);
            callback();
        });
    });
}
```

export default publish;

**sample log from cloudwatch:**

> START RequestId: ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27 Version: $LATEST
>   2018-03-27T07:24:41.744Z  ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27    test
>   started
>   2018-03-27T07:24:41.744Z  ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27    publish
>   started
>   2018-03-27T07:24:41.767Z  ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27    connected
>   to the queue
>   2018-03-27T07:24:41.767Z  ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27    message
>   to publish: "{\"floatId\":0.24342369749799642}"
>   2018-03-27T07:24:41.767Z  ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27    err:
>   undefined
>   2018-03-27T07:24:41.767Z  ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27    packet:
>   undefined
>   2018-03-27T07:24:41.767Z  ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27    calling
>   the callback END RequestId: ea63e6ca-318f-11e8-b766-b78fb7754d27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that you should call `client#end` method after publishing this single message. This might look cumbersome but in case you want to keep publishing again and again over the calls to your Lambda function, I think this will reduce the chances that you need to open the connection again.

```
client.addListener('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected to the queue');
    console.log(`message to publish: ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
    client.publish(topic, message, (err, packet) => {
        console.log(`err: ` + err);
        console.log(`packet: ${JSON.stringify(packet)}`);
        client.end(false, () => callback()); //This line should be added then it works as expected

    });
});
```